# Как взять результат из таблице только если все объекты по признаку удовлетворяют условию?

Tags: sql, plpgsql

Есть таблица:

| id | order_id | accepted | success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 131 | true | null |
| 2 | 131 | false | null |
| 3 | 132 | false | null |
| 4 | 133 | true | true |
| 5 | 134 | true | true |
| 6 | 134 | true | true |
| 7 | 134 | true | null |
| 8 | 135 | true | false |
| 9 | 135 | true | true |
| 10 | 135 | false | null |

Нужно вернуть сгруппированные `order_id`, где `все` записи по этому `order_id` удовлетворяют `accpted notnull` и ((`accpted = true` и `success notnull`) или `accepted = false`) (в контексте одного `order_id`).
То-есть из таблицы должно вернуться - 132, 133, 135.

131 не возвращается так как у первой записи `accepted = true а success isnull`.

134 не возвращается так как у седьмой записи `accepted = true а success isnull`.

Вот так пробую:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.order_id
    FROM orders.order_flow t1
    WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM orders.order_flow t2
                WHERE t1.order_id = t2.order_id
                    AND (t2.accepted = TRUE AND t2.success NOTNULL)
                   OR t2.accepted = FALSE) =
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders.order_flow t3 WHERE t3.order_id = t1.order_id));
```

но алгоритм не правильный, так как под-запрос захватывает записи относящиеся к другому `order_id`.

И так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.order_id
    FROM orders.order_flow t1
    WHERE EXISTS(
            SELECT
                FROM orders.order_flow t2
                WHERE t1.order_id = t2.order_id
                  AND ((t2.accepted = TRUE AND t2.success NOTNULL)
                    OR t2.accepted = FALSE))
```

Но тогда при таких данных:

| id | order_id | accepted | success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | false | null |
| 2 | 200 | true | null |

Выдает 200, что не правильно, так как у второй записи `accepted = true, а success isnull`

Comment: прочитал несколько по диагонали, но чую надо посчитать что-то вроде `select product_id, count(id) as c, sum(case when .... then 1 else 0 end)  as s ... having с = s` , или нет?

Comment: или просто `select product id ... having count() = sum(case ... )`